# Logic - logical connective for (~ABC) + (A~BC) + (AB~C)?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Is there a logical connective that says 'True, if and only if 1 proposition is true'.

Or perhaps even better, is there one that describes 'True, if and only if n propositions is true'? Where n is an arbitrary integer.

Comment: There is exclusive-or: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or

Comment: @Jed and OP: note that $A_1\oplus A_2\oplus\cdots \oplus A_n$ is the set of elements contained in $A_i$ for an odd number of $i$, so $A\oplus B\oplus C$ doesn't quite fit the OP's request.

Comment: @JMoravitz yeah I always found that really stupid, surely it's not as helpful